# SwiftUI List - disable moving of particular rows?

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, row, move

In a SwiftUI `List` that is in `Edit` mode, each row has a handle at its trailing edge so that the row can be moved up or down in the sequence of rows. In UIKit there is an instance method `tableView(_:canMoveRowAt:)` which specifies which rows contains those handles and which do not.

I'm seeking the equivalent in SwiftUI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `.moveDisabled(condition)` modifier, like in below example

```
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
          .moveDisabled(item == "nonmovable item")    // << conditional !!
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - I never would have found that in all the ViewModifiers listed!!